# Template class specialization and friend classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

I am in the following situation:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class Foo
{
};

// specialization for 0
template<typename T>
class Foo<0>
{
   friend class Foo<T, 1>;
};
```

That is, I need that `Foo<T, 1>` is friend of `Foo<T, 0>`, but I have a compiler error. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo in your specialization:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo<T, 0>
{     //  ^^^ <= add this
   friend class Foo<T, 1>;
};
```